# How to calculate the weeknumber using dayOfYear

Tags: c#, date, time

I am currently trying to calculate the weeknumber using the dayOfYear

```
string dateStr = $"{Model.Date:dddd, d MMMM}";
Date.Text = char.ToUpper(dateStr[0]) + dateStr.Substring(1);

WeekOfYear.Text = $"Week {Model.Date.DayOfYear / 7}";
```

The only thing is this sometimes gives back the wrong weeknumber because it gives back a double and not a weeknumber.

Is there a better way to calculate this?

Comment: Look for modulo divison

Comment: Always use already implemented functionality for things like date and time. There are many special cases to care about. I.e. a week is assigned to the year its thursday(?) belongs to. So the 01.01 is still the last week of the previous year if it's a saturday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
int numeroSemana = ObterNumeroSemana(Convert.ToDateTime(visita["dataPrevistaVisita"].ToString()));

public static int ObterNumeroSemana(DateTime dataVisita)
{
  CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
  int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dataVisita, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
  return weekNum;

}
```

If you have questions let me know. Cheers.